# how to send a picture from server to client in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to python and i can't figure out what's wrong with my code here :

I set up a client and a server (both on localhost) , the server take a snapshot and suppose to send it to the client which saves it in some folder , it's all happening , but the JPG file doesn't open the picture correctly , instead it's says that it doesn't support the file format :\

the code:

clientFile.py

```
import socket

# set up a socket connection object
my_socket = socket.socket()
# make the socket connect to a certain ip&port
my_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8821))

data = ''

while data != 'EXIT':
    message = input('enter a message to send to the server \n')
    # send the server what to do (in this case take a snapshot)
    my_socket.send(message.encode())
    
    data = my_socket.recv(1024).decode()
   
    if data == 'snapshot has been taken':
        # recieve the file's byte length from the server ( for example: 2000000 bytes => 7 length)
        data = my_socket.recv(1).decode()
        
        sizeLength = int(data) % 10
        # recieve the size of the file picture
        data = my_socket.recv(sizeLength).decode()
        size = int(data)

        # recieve the file in binary
        picture = my_socket.recv(size)
        # trying to write the file :\
        myfile = open(r'C:\test\client\screen.jpg', 'wb')
        myfile.write(picture)
        myfile.close()
else:
    print('closing the socket')
    my_socket.close()
```

server.py

```
    import socket
    import datetime
    import glob
    import os
    import pyautogui
    import subprocess
    
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    # accepting a socket from which client (0.0.0.0) means everyone
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 8821))
    server_socket.listen()
    # accept sockets and recieve socket and client ip&port as tuples
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    
    # data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    data = ''
    while data != 'EXIT':
    .
    .
    .
        elif data == 'SNAPSHOT':
            #snapshot saved succesfully !
            image = pyautogui.screenshot()
            image.save(r'C:\test\screen.jpg') 

            # file stats (size and stuff)
            picStats = os.stat(r'C:\test\screen.jpg')
            
            picSize = picStats.st_size
            picLength = len(str(picSize))
          
            
            myfile = open(r'C:\test\screen.jpg', 'rb')
            print(myfile.read())
            reply = 'snapshot has been taken'
            # make the client prepere for the picture to be send
            client_socket.send(reply.encode())
            # send the picture length
             client_socket.send(str(picLength).encode())
            # send the picture size 
            client_socket.send(str(picSize).encode())
            client_socket.send(myfile.read())
            
.
.
.
#closing sockets eventually ...
```

i think i'm missing something here...
thanks

Comment: Open the file in an editor (one that supports display information in hex as well), and look at the differences before and after sending the file. In particular I'm guessing your calls to `recv` contains more data than you expect, or that you're using the size information wrong (seeing as it's being sent as a string on one side, and then only read as a single byte (?) on the other side)

Comment: Please edit your code in your question so it is a [mre] - in particular remove those ... sections and make it runnable minimal example. Anyone should be able to copy/paste your code into two files and _without adding anything_ run it to see the same result as you.. Your code isn’t restricted to sending a JPEG file, you should be able to send a file with ascii content - first thing I’d do is check that the receiving end if getting the correct size for the file. Also you should allow the receiving end to receive fewer bytes than the full length and save them to file then go wait for the rest.

Comment: Have you looked at multiprocessing module?  These issues are solved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have one issue with the code:

```
# This reads all the bytes in the file 
print(myfile.read())

# this will read nothing since the file cursor is already at the end of the file. 
client_socket.send(myfile.read())
```

Either set the bytes to an internal object `file_bytes= myfile.read()` or reset the cursor between reads `myfile.seek(0)`

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND MAN!
thanks!
Such a silly mistake